# Updating python tkinter Labels

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import time

master = Tk()

def uiPrint():
    print("")
    print(click)


click = 0
mult = 1
clickView = click

def doubClicks():
    global click
    global mult
    if click < 5:
        print("Not enough clicks!")
    elif click >= 5:
        mult = mult*2
        click = click - 5
        print("Double Clicks Purchased!")

def buttonCommand():
    clickView = IntVar()
    Label(master, textvariable =clickView).pack()
    clickView.get()
    global click
    global mult
    click += 1*(mult)
    uiPrint()

mainClickButton = Button(master, text="Click!", command = buttonCommand)
mainClickButton.pack()

purchaseDoubleClickButton = Button(master, text="Purchase Double Clicks", command = doubClicks)
purchaseDoubleClickButton.pack()


master.title("Clicker")
master.geometry("%sx%s+%s+%s" % (200,70,512,512))
mainloop()
```

The Problem:

The label on the tkinter window that tells you how many clicks you have stays at 0, doesent update. What is the problem? Probably missing something really obvious

Answer (score 0):

I think you should update the same instance of your IntVar in order for the content to be updated.What you should do is create your IntVar in the main program and use it as global inside the buttonCommand() function:

```
def buttonCommand():    
    global click
    global mult
    global clickView
    click += 1*(mult)
    clickView.set(click)
    uiPrint()

mainClickButton = Button(master, text="Click!", command = buttonCommand)
mainClickButton.pack()

purchaseDoubleClickButton = Button(master, text="Purchase Double Clicks", command = doubClicks)
purchaseDoubleClickButton.pack()

clickView = IntVar()
clickView.set(click)
Label(master, textvariable = clickView).pack()
```

**EDIT:**
To update the label when a double click is purchased you use the same method on the "doubleClicks" function:

```
def doubClicks():
    global click
    global mult
    global clickView
    if click < 5:
        print("Not enough clicks!")
    elif click >= 5:
        mult = mult*2
        click = click - 5
        print("Double Clicks Purchased!")
    clickView.set(click)
```

Another approach is to use OOP, so creating a "clicker" class instead of using globals:

```
from Tkinter import *

class Clicker():
    def __init__(self, master):            
        self.click = 0
        self.mult = 1
        self.clickView = StringVar() 
        self.clickView.set(self.click)

        self.mainClickButton = Button(master, text="Click!", command =  self.buttonCommand)
        self.mainClickButton.pack()

        self.purchaseDoubleClickButton = Button(master, text="Purchase Double Clicks", command = self.doubClicks)
        self.purchaseDoubleClickButton.pack()

        Label(master, textvariable = self.clickView).pack()


    def uiPrint(self):
        print("")
        print(self.click)

    def doubClicks(self):
        if self.click < 5:
            print("Not enough clicks!")
        elif self.click >= 5:
            self.mult = self.mult*2
            self.click = self.click - 5
            print("Double Clicks Purchased!")
            self.clickView.set(self.click)

    def buttonCommand(self):              
        self.click += 1*(self.mult)
        self.clickView.set(self.click)
        self.uiPrint()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    master = Tk()        
    master.title("Clicker")
    master.geometry("%sx%s+%s+%s" % (200,70,512,512))  
    clicker = Clicker(master)

    mainloop()
```

Comment: Also consider building a class and avoiding the use of globals.

Comment: This works, although when double clicks is purchased for 5 it doesent subtract from the amount on the window?

Comment: You use the same strategy on the "doubClicks" function. I have updated the answer.